# JQuery AJAX problem

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf

Not too sure what happened here. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 .NET 4. With the following code, I WAS using JQuery 1.4.2 - with JQuery 1.4.2 the code worked just great. I'm calling a restful WCF RESTFUL method.

I created a simple Client with the following code:

```
Type = "POST";
    Url = "http://localhost:60922/servicestart/SaveAllClients";
    ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

    DataType = "json"; ProcessData = true;
    method = "SavePersons";
    Data = JSON.stringify(formApplication);

    CallService();


function CallService() {

     $.ajax({
          type: Type, //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
          url: Url, // Location of the service
          data: Data, //Data sent to server
          contentType: ContentType, // content type sent to server
          dataType: DataType, //Expected data format from server
          processdata: ProcessData,    //True or False
          success: function(msg) {//On Successfull service call
           ServiceSucceeded(msg);
          },
       error: ServiceFailed// When Service call fails
      });
     }
```

Now, the restful code in a separate project:

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "SaveAllClients", Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        [OperationContract]
        public string SavePersons(Person peeps)
        {

            string xml = string.Empty;

            XMLToolset x = new XMLToolset();
            xml = x.SerializeToXML(peeps);

            xml = peeps.SerializeToXML(peeps);

            // send xml to Oracle -


             string json = string.Empty;

            Person p = new Person();
            p.first_name = "Good";
            p.middle_name = "Happy";
            p.last_name = "GH";

            json = p.ConvertToJson(p);

            return json;

        }
```

Now using jquery 1.4.2 the code worked really well - basically it is a cross domain request. I decided to swap out jquery 1.4.2 to jquery 1.6.2 - for the sake of staying up to date - and well - it doesn't work now - it reports a service error O.

I studied the ajax documentation and the new features in jquery 1.5.2 and noticed a few things such as setting cross domain to true or using jsonp but neither of those worked.

Has something else changed in 1.6.2 from 1.4.2 in terms of how ajax functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is not working **NOT** because you switched from jQuery 1.4.2 to 1.6.2 but because you put your WCF service in a separate project. So I guess you hosted it in a separate application => you are now violating the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). And this policy has nothing to do with jQuery. It's a browser limitation.

So if you want to make this working you could configure your [WCF service to use JSONP](http://bendewey.wordpress.com/2009/11/24/using-jsonp-with-wcf-and-jquery/).

Comment: Here's the thing - in both instances - the two projects were always separate.

Comment: @dawriter, I don't know. What I know is that if you don't use JSONP you cannot do cross domain AJAX calls.

Comment: Thanks, Darin - if you have any best practices links I can study that utilizes WCF restful services, I'd be grateful.

Comment: @dawriter, the one I posted in my answer for doing JSONP and solving your current problem might be a good start. As far as designing RESTful services in WCF is concerned you could take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/cc950529

Answer (score 0):

May be you moved your service into a seperate project caused this issue.